# vsto addin for excel 2016 events not fired

Tags: excel, visual-studio, events, vsto, excel-addins

since few weeks (last update ?) when i doubleclick on an xlsx file in the explorer, excel launch as well but no events are fired...

it is very easy to reproduce :
create an vsto excel addin project in visual studio

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
}

private void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ExcelAddin AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler event fired");
}
```

In debug mode, i set the following parameters :

- start external program : c:...\excel.exe
- command line argument : full path of the xlsx filename

If i launch excel and i open the file with the menu (File/Open) the event is fired !

Thanks for help!